# Python WWS Library requires entire certificate chain to verify server

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, certificate, wss

I am using ssl.py to connect to a webserver and I would like to verify the server certificate.

I have a ROOT_CA which signs an INTERMEDIATE_CA and this finally signs the SERVER_CERTIFICATE.

I would like to provide the client only the INTERMEDIATE_CA so it can verify all certificates signed by it. However, it appears that I need to provide the entire certificate chain ROOT_CA->INTERMEDIATE_CA in order for the verification to work.

Any insights on this ?

Here is the script I am using:

```
import asyncio
import pathlib
import ssl
import websockets

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
ssl_context.check_hostname = False
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED 
server_cert = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("intermediate_ca_server.ca-chain.cert.pem")
ssl_context.load_verify_locations(server_cert)

async def hello():
     uri = "wss://<url>"
     async with websockets.connect(
         uri, ssl=ssl_context
     ) as websocket:
        await websocket.send('test data')
        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {greeting}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default OpenSSL needs the full certificate chain including the root certificate. With OpenSSL 1.0.2 a new verification flag `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN` was added which makes it possible to let the trust chain end in a trusted certificate even if this certificate is not a root certificate (i.e. subject and issuer differ).

It looks like Python does not have yet a constant defined for this so one needs to use the integer representation:

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile='subca.pem')  # contains only sub-CA
ctx.verify_flags |= 0x80000           # set X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN
ctx.ssl_wrap(...)
```