# Certificate Verify Failed when using Requests in Python with a self signed certificate

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I'm using python to access Aruba switches through an API. I'm wanting to use HTTPS so that my traffic (that is sending usernames and passwords for verification) is encrypted:

```
import requests
import json
import base64
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
import certifi

url = 'https://10.4.10.10/rest/v3/'
creds = {'userName': 'username', 'password': 'password'}
command = 'show config'

s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url + 'login-sessions', data=json.dumps(creds), timeout=1)
print(r.json())
cookie_response = r.json()['cookie']
if r.status_code != 201:
    print('Login error, status code {}'.format(r.status_code))
```

I generated a self signed certificate in the CLI and then was able to grab it by putting the ip address into chrome (with https:// in front of it) and then downloading the certificate file. I had to use openssl to convert the certificate file type into a .pem. Finally, I opened the file in a text editor and added the certificate to the end of the cacert.pem file that is used by the Requests module. After doing all this, I still get the following error:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)
```

I've searched all over, but still can't find a solution. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

-EDIT-

Here is the contents of the certificate I am using:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            17:13:91:1c:86:72:ae:bd:01:27:28:39:8f:4e:5a:2d:18:ae:1f:04
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=testSwitch, OU=OCSwitch, O=OC, L=Edmond, ST=Oklahoma, C=US
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 16 10:59:12 2020 GMT
            Not After : Jun 16 23:59:59 2021 GMT
        Subject: CN=testSwitch, OU=OCSwitch, O=OC, L=Edmond, ST=Oklahoma, C=US
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus (1024 bit):
                    00:be:6a:27:02:f5:6a:98:19:0f:db:c7:11:26:dd:
                    77:26:bd:18:ef:ab:62:53:3e:13:a1:61:b0:5a:88:
                    77:d8:ba:81:56:2a:7d:66:0a:2c:cd:f1:78:4b:35:
                    61:73:31:4c:4f:80:51:21:86:bf:2c:1c:95:87:cc:
                    e7:5f:47:d8:d8:6e:ed:d4:4f:56:79:24:01:65:c9:
                    72:cb:6c:7a:55:ef:9b:1b:ae:4e:28:8f:27:50:1d:
                    36:08:c3:85:67:2c:8a:1a:42:15:83:d2:e3:b3:ef:
                    d3:ce:cd:77:d5:3f:25:f5:b3:c1:ce:e8:7c:e1:cb:
                    fc:c5:12:e8:0a:d0:87:1b:4d
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Key Agreement
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        51:01:6c:13:40:8a:73:70:96:71:ea:b1:4b:b1:36:c3:82:ed:
        2b:3a:d8:b3:23:77:6e:bb:56:d5:71:56:ff:0a:66:4f:81:69:
        ef:33:9e:1f:ff:20:3e:49:70:c4:8b:c9:92:65:ce:80:78:62:
        0e:e4:8e:39:ee:e0:04:6d:73:67:41:1a:dd:1e:ec:19:af:45:
        0b:f3:4b:2e:88:10:5e:c1:89:6b:37:d1:12:a7:23:e1:86:94:
        4f:b2:8a:fd:62:d6:33:5f:14:62:50:2e:38:0f:b1:46:55:ad:
        46:71:df:b3:6d:44:48:c9:72:f5:0b:0a:13:ed:9a:2f:05:5c:
        05:0b
```

I've modified my code by importing ssl and using ssl.get_server_certificate():

```
import ssl

cert = ssl.get_server_certificate(('10.4.10.10', 443))
with open('cert.pem', 'w') as file:
    file.write(cert)
```

I then point to 'cert.pem' with verify= and still get the same error.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: @Ethan Primarily using macOS, but I've also run it in Windows with the same setup and I receive the same error.

Comment: Could you please provide details of the certificate, i.e. add the output of `openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.pem` to your question?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I added the output in the question.

Comment: @PeytonChenault: *"I added the output in the question"* - no, this is the content of the `cert.pem` but not the output of `openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.pem` which I've explicitly requested. If you would have provided the full certificate I could create the output myself but not just with this snippet.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Sorry for the misunderstanding, I've added the details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Key Agreement
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Server Authentication
```

This is a leaf certificate and not a CA certificate (no basic constraints CA:true). OpenSSL historically requires the trust anchor for verification to be a self-signed CA certificate though.

This is changed only with newer versions (OpenSSL 1.0.2 and later) when the option `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN` is used in certificate verification. In this case an arbitrary CA certificate in the CA store would work as trust anchor and also self-signed certificates without CA:true seem to work.

Unfortunately this flag is not exposed in Python yet and I see no way to specify custom verify options or a custom context with special verify options to `requests`. With other libraries this might be more doable, see [Python WWS Library requires entire certificate chain to verify server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327424/python-wws-library-requires-entire-certificate-chain-to-verify-server).

Comment: Does this happen because my certificate is self signed, or is it due to the way I am generating the certificate?

Comment: @PeytonChenault: If the certificate would be self-signed and also have CA:true then it would work. So it is likely the (unknown) way you use to create the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if the certificates were imported from the root level to the bottom of the chain? Also, try to pass the path to the certificate file in the requests function to see if the certificate works:

```
r = s.post(url, data=data, verify='/path/to/public_key.pem')
```

Comment: I tried to specify the path with verify= and still got the same error. Tried both the cacert.pem file provided by certifi and the .pem file I got with openssl. And the certificates were imported from the root level.

Comment: @Peyton Chenault Could you please specify more details on the issue.I assume you have a server running with HTTPS enabled and self signed certificate in it and you have imported the .pem certificate from the browser.The requests library must be able to get throught ssl conenction with the verify parameter and the absolute path to the .pem file in your file system. I have tested for connecting to a apache server with https enabled with self signed certificate and was successful with the verify parameter pointing to the .pem certificate.

Comment: All of your assumptions are correct. I'm starting to think that the certificate that I pulled from the browser may not be the correct one, but I'm not sure of another way to get it for my server.