# How can I use a custom SSL certificate with Python requests client?

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, certificate, client

**using custom SSL certificate with python requests**

I'm working on a client that connects to servers with custom SSL certificates. In my database I have a certificate downloaded from that website (certificate downloaded by clicking on the padlock. icon next to the address bar in the browser, and then stored in db with base64 encoding).

Im trying to execute a request with the following:

```
    def execute_get_request_with_custom_certificate(self, url:str, headers:dict):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp_cert_file:
            cert = get_certificate_from_db()
            decoded_cert = base64.b64decode(cert)
            temp_cert_file.write(decoded_cert)
            temp_cert_file.flush()
            return requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=temp_cert_file.name)
```

unfortunately all the time I receive the following error:
`Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:897)'),)`

I have gone through documentation of "requests" package, couldn't find a solution there.
I have verified the content of the created temporary file content against the content of the file downloaded from the server using "cmp" command. They were the same.

My other thoughts:

1. Maybe there is something lost/modified in the certificate during the base64 encoding (EOL marks?), but the "cmp" shows that the created file is the same as the downloaded one.
2. This is not the certificate that should be used with the "verify" parameter. Documentation refers also to CA_BUNDLE file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is your variable "file" correct? or should be "temp_cert_file"? try to remove 1 indent on the return to be outside the "with": to be sure file is close

Comment: The certificate must be in PEM format

Comment: @Wonka 
Yes, it should be "temp_cert_file" instead of "file". 
I don't think moving outside of the indentation would work here. This is a tempfile wrapper on the file, when I leave the "with" context, the file will be closed and deleted.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich what exactly do you mean? I have also tried using "cryptography" package to create a x.509 certificate with the data and storing in the file the returned value of certificate.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM). Still no luck.

Comment: Also make sure that the certificate has actually basic constrainsts CA:true set, which is common (but not always the case) for self-signed certificates but not the case for CA signed server certificates. Without this flag it is not considered a CA and will not be used for validation.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The certificate does not have the constraint CA:true. IT does not have the section Certificate Basic Constraints (As I understand, I should look for: Extensions>'Certificate Basic Constraints'>'Is a Certification Authority').

Comment: @SteffenUllrich
***"certificate downloaded by clicking on the padlock icon next to the address bar in the browser"*** is this the correct way to get the certificate? maybe this is where I get it wrong...

Comment: If the certificate does not have CA:true then the format does not matter - it will not work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62416452/certificate-verify-failed-when-using-requests-in-python-with-a-self-signed-certi