# urllib3 self-signed certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, ssl, urllib3

I am attempting to connect to a third party system and this will be using self-signed certificates from both sides as this will not be public internet facing.

I am using Python 3 with urllib3 Pool Manager. I have a copy of the certificate, the private key and the verification certificate from the third party. Utilising these in curl confirms the connection works:

```
curl https://third_party_url.com/hello -iv --cert ./cert.cert --cacert ./verify.cert   --key ./key.key
```

However, when I try to utilise this in code:

```
client = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_file = "./cert.cert",
    key_file="./key.key",
    ca_certs="./verify.cert",
    cert_reqs="CERT_REQUIRED"
)
resp = client.request("GET", "https://third_party_url.com/hello")
```

An exception occurs:

```
    Exception has occurred: SSLError
   [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)
```

A lot of the answers to similar questions is about disabling the verification, which is definitely not an option. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Answers to the questions raised by @Steffen

1)
When running without the `-cacert` argument, curl provides this output:

```
*   Trying 10.10.10.10:443...
* Connected to third_party_url.com (10.10.10.10) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

So it's the same issue. It's like urllib3 is not accepting the argument to load a provided one.

2)
On running `openssl x509 -in verify.cert -text`
The output does not have basic constraints set to CA:true.

The output is:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number:
            <SerialNumber>
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = GB, O = me.com, OU = third-party
        Validity
            Not Before: Valid Date
            Not After : Expiry Date
        Subject: C = GB, O = Third Party Company Name, OU = third-party, CN = *third-party.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
            <Modulus>
                Exponent: <Redacted Value>
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
    <Signature Value>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<Certificate Details>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Could you please check that 1. curl fails when the `-cacert` argument is not given, i.e. that the given verify.cert is actually essential and 2. that when getting the details for verify.cert (like with `openssl x509 -in verify.cert -text`) you see basic constrains set to CA:true.

Comment: I have edited my post with the answer to your questions @SteffenUllrich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    ...
    Issuer: C = GB, O = me.com, OU = third-party
    ...
    Subject: C = GB, O = Third Party Company Name, OU = third-party, CN = *third-party.com
```

The issuer and subject of this certificate differ. So this is not a self-signed root CA which is expected as a trust anchor.

By default OpenSSL (which is used by Python as SSL library) will not treat an intermediate certificate like this as the trust anchor. This is only done if `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN` is explicitly set, which is not done by Python but [since a while by curl](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/4655).

So this explains why it succeeds with curl but not with Python.

See also [Python WWS Library requires entire certificate chain to verify server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327424/python-wws-library-requires-entire-certificate-chain-to-verify-server) on how to deal with this issue by setting the appropriate option on the SSL context.

Apart from that - this certificate is a very old X509v2 certificate which does not support extensions. Modern certificates are X509v3 and also have the domain names there are valid for in a Subject Alternative Names extensions. Relevant modern software like Chrome browser will complain about certificates like this.

Comment: Perfect explanation and link to useful information. Through this I have solved the issue. Thanks!